# JQuery UI draggable not working at all!

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Why does this not work at all for me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    $('.selector').draggable({ axis: 'x' });    });

    </script>

    <body>

    <div class="selector">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
```

I have literally just copied and pasted from the draggable example page on the jQuery site and it just doesn't work :(

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the order of the javascript includes, the jQuery core file always comes first.

Comment: That's it.  I was able to get it to run when I switched those.

Comment: I cant believe that actually worked :|

Thanks for that, twas frustrating

Comment: jQuery UI is a jQuery plugin, just like every other jQuery plugin it needs jQuery to be loaded before it.

Answer (score 5):

May sound trivial but you need to load the jQuery library before jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.selector').draggable({ axis: 'x' });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <div class="selector">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
```